# Can not connect to VirtualBox via SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox

I am trying to learn `SSH` by using `Ubuntu 16.04` as client and another `Ubuntu 16.04` as the server which is running in `Oracle VirtualBox`.
As far as I know everything is done right, but after executing `sudo ssh -p 2222 cockroach@127.0.0.1` I receive the following message:

> ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

These are the logs from host's `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
cockroach : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; 
COMMAND=/usr/bin/ssh -p2222 cockroach@127.0.0.1
pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by cockroach(uid=0)
pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

And the followings are the log messages from guest's `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
ubuntu2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by cockroach(uid=0)
ubuntu2 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

I also made the `ufw` to let `SSH` data transmission for both the client and server but, my problem still exists. 
Would you please give me some ideas about where my problem might be from?

Comment: Why are you running `sudo ssh...` instead of `ssh...` ?  Can you edit your question to include more verbose output `ssh -vv ...` ?

Comment: @user4556274: I have uncomented the `Port` from server's `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` to be `22`. I have also forwarded the ports in virtualbox as the guest should work on port number 22. But by executing `ssh -p 22 root@127.0.0.1` and enterinig the password needed, ssh command shows the main system's directory and not the one located in VirtualBOX. help me please.

Comment: Can you share your sshd_config and what is the service status (sudo systemctl status sshd)...?

Answer (score 2):

This might seem obvious but don't forget to install the service in the VM:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y openssh-server
```

You also need to forward from e.g. `127.0.0.1` port `8022` to `10.0.2.15` port `22` via the *Advanced* options in the *Networks* tab of the VM settings *Port Forwarding* screen.

Then you can connect:

```
ssh -p 8022 user@127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

/etc/ssh/sshd_config contains `PermitRootLogin no` (the default)

Comment: in my case it is `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`. What shall I change it to? the fun part is not using `sudo` still results in the same condition !!

Comment: cockroach has uid=0, so in fact cockroach is root (I abhor that).  sudo or not doesn't matter, it's the "root@127.0.0.1" that's being cut off.

Comment: Executing `ssh -p 2222 root@127.0.0.1` does not work either !!

Answer (score 0):

With `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` you'll need to use another authentication method, as public/private keys, for example.

If you wish to use root login/password (no problem doing it in a LAB environment) you could use `PermitRootLogin yes`.

EDIT: Reviewing this thread I just saw the @127.0.0.1... Are you connecting FROM the VirtualBox VM itself?

Please give us more details like:
1 - In which machine are you editing sshd.conf
2 - In which one are you running the ssh command
3 - To which one are you trying to connect.

I'm suspecting that it's more trivial than it looked at first, but please, give as most details as you can.

Comment: The change is done, and yet the error message is still given back !

Comment: Have you restarted sshd ?